# Create OpenOffice ODT document RUBY

Tags: ruby, openoffice-writer, odt

I am looking for a Ruby Gem that will allow me to create openoffice odt documents from scratch. There is also a requirement to include images in said documents. Has anyone come across a gem offering this functionality. I have not been able to find any that will facilitate the creation of new documents (replacing text in a template doc is pretty straight forward).

Regards and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is [serenity-odt](https://rubygems.org/gems/serenity-odt) listed on [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) or [this post](http://viewyonder.com/2010/10/14/working-with-openoffice-files-from-ruby/) that describes some work similar to what you describe.